# I can't see private members in a Kotlin KClass

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

I'm working on a library that uses reflection, and I would like to manipulate all the properties / function of a given KClass.

Using the `KClass::members` property, I can manipulate all the accessible members (as per the documentation), ie: the public, internal and protected fields, properties and functions. But I can't see the private ones.

Using Java reflection, I can see all fields (inluding private ones) using the `Class.getDeclaredFields()`, and likewise I can see private methods using `Class.getDeclaredMethods()`.

Is there a way to do this using the kotlin reflection API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`declaredMembers`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-members.html), [`declaredFunctions`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-functions.html), and [`declaredMemberProperties`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/declared-member-properties.html), which will include the private members, but won't include the members declared in the supertypes, just like with the Java reflection API.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid. I only looked at the KClass documentation, but didn't think there would be an extension function to do that.